# Flutter: Arabic/Kurdish text rendering issue on web only

Tags: flutter

I'm having a problem that I need help with. I'm using Arabic/Kurdish text in a simple Text widget, and it works perfectly on mobile. However, when I try it on the web platform, things go wrong.

To be honest, I'm not sure why this is happening. Take a look at the example I've shown in "Actual Result 1" below. You'll see that the issue mostly affects the Text widget, while the app bar seems to be fine.

Here is the code for the first image :

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:kleely/screens/admin/admin_drawer.dart';
    
    class AdminMainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      const AdminMainScreen({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          drawer: const AdminDrawer(),
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('سەرپەرشتیار'),
          ),
          body: const Center(
            child: Text('سەرپەرشتیار'),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

As you can see its just a normal text widget and when its on web i get issues like getting bold or the text gets unreadable

### Expected results should be like this:
[image: Expected result 1]

[image: Expected result 2]

### And this is what im getting sometimes worse than just the text gets bold here are some screen shots:
[image: Actual result 1]

[image: Actual resutl 2]

These are some that only gets bold but sometimes its not just bold and i get these for the first image here is the code :

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class SubscriptionOverlayBanner extends StatelessWidget {
      final VoidCallback onPressed;
    
      const SubscriptionOverlayBanner({super.key, required this.onPressed});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    
        return Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          height: screenHeight * 0.2,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height:
                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2, // 20% of screen height
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.9),
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20)),
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16, horizontal: 24),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'بەشداری هیچ پلانێکت نییە تکایە پلانێک دیاری بکە',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 16),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: onPressed,
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 12),
                      child: Text("بەشداری پالن بکە", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

The Images:

### [image: Worse results 1]

[image: Worse results 2]

Here is flutter doctor:

```
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.0, on macOS 14.0 23A5328b darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
    [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    [✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    [✓] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
    [✓] Connected device (3 available)
        ! Error: Arivan’s iPhone is busy: Fetching debug symbols for Arivan’s iPhone. Xcode will continue when Arivan’s iPhone is finished. (code -10)
    [✓] Network resources
```

Comment: I've edited my answer, look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be solved by changing the render engine to Canvaskit

```
flutter build web --release --web-renderer canvaskit
```

Answer (score -1):

I've edited the code you've put in here, this should help.
This code removes the issues with the default limits of the text size, eliminating those awkward yellow lines that appear when the Widgets take more space than it's given to them, and places the text inside the containers with the necessary space, removing unwanted styles.

```
DefaultTextStyle(
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 18,
    ),
    child: Text(
      'بەشداری هیچ پلانێکت نییە تکایە پلانێک دیاری بکە',
    ),
),
```